# Ambiguous output redirect error in find command

Tags: find, io-redirection, tcsh

Apologies if this is a repeated question, I am trying to search for a file in all the subdirectories in a given path. While doing so I also want to suppress any output messages, errors from the `find` command, so I am using the following command:

```
find -L a/b/c/d/e -name file_name.xml -type f -print 2>/dev/null | xargs -l1 dirname
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Ambiguous output redirect.
```

If I remove `2>/dev/null` from my command I get the output message :

```
a/b/c/d/e/my_folder/file_name.xml
```

Kindly give some guidance how to solve

Comment: What is your actual file name or path? Possible that it contains `>` ?

Comment: What is the shell you're using?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am using tcsh as shell,                                                                 > echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh

Comment: @pLumo I checked the  file name and path , both of them don't contain ">"

Comment: you should still quote the file names ..., but yeah, maybe some `tcsh` issue, I don't use that.